# Can I use C++ and Qt on iPad 2?

Tags: c++, qt, ipad-2

I work with Qt in Ubuntu. I bought an iPad 2 yesterday and I don't know if I can compile C++/Qt on it. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4):

You don't.  QT is not supported on iOS

To learn more about developing apps for iOS, see apple's dev site:

http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action

Answer (score 2):

There is a community project that allows to run a Qt app on iPhone using QtLighthouse. But the performance is terrible and it was created only to demonstrate QtLighthouse capabilities. The general answer is: No, its neither officially supported nor legal from Apple license perspective to run Qt app on an iPhone/iPad

Comment: It's not legal?  Could you elaborate?

Comment: Matt, I'm not an expert in this kind of questions (licensing on Apple platform) but apparently you can't redistribute your iPhone app through Apple App Store if the app is written in Qt. There is something with the API that doesn't allow you to do it

Comment: Wow that is lame.  Ok, hello Smartphone/Android.  Thanks--

Answer (score 1):

You can run Objective-C++ applications on the iPad 2. Specifically you'll need some Objective-C boilerplate for the application's essentials but you are free to use C++ in your own code.

As others have stated, Qt development is not supported on iOS.